# How to fix "login failed for user" when manipulating SQL database in Azure from a .NET Core webapp?

Tags: sql, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an SQL Database in Azure and a .Net Core web app in which I would like to manipulate the database using Entity Framework Core.

I believe I have all the model, data and controller classes needed for this, and I have a few sample objects I'd like to see in my database.

My problem is that no matter what I do or how I want to manipulate the database, I always get the error "login failed for user", yet the login info is an admin and I believe I set up everything that is needed.

I see the database in the SQL Server Object Explorer, I can connect to it using SSMS or simply on the Azure Portal, and there seems to be no problem with my connection string. The username&password combo is fine, I've checked it multiple times, my IP is enabled in the firewall of the database, I have no idea what could be the problem, please help me!

Here is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved now, it was a very tiny, stupid error:

the connection string I copied from the Azure site was waiting for an escaped field, assuming I won't write my username and password manually, which of course won't be happening in the future, I just wanted to test if the whole stuff worked as this is my first project in this area.

So the Azure connection string looked like this: `USER={XY};PASSWORD={ASD}` but I left the curly brackets in the string even though I didn't use a variable there.

Comment: Glad to see you have fixed your problem!

Comment: lol, I did the same dumb thing! Thanks for catching it for me. ':)

Answer (score 0):

I test and it works fine. So I am doubt about whether you could run it in local with the connectionstring of Azure sql database.

Open your azure sql server on portal and click your sql database.

[image]

Click the Connection string and copy the connectionstring. Filled into your username and password.
[image]

Then put it to the connection string in appsettings.json on visual studio.
If you could run on local, then you publish will have no problem.

Also, you could follow this article to learn with [asp.net core mvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by local? If I put the connection string of my azure database in the json file (which I've already done), it still tries to connect to that database, that's what I was trying and I get this error.

Comment: Commonly, if you put the connectionstring in appsettings.json, and your username and password are right, it will work fine.

Comment: Yes, I suppose, that's my problem, that it doesn't. I copied the exact connection string from where you suggested in the first place, put my admin login info, and it throws an exception that "login failed for user". :(

Comment: Do you have a master database, or if you connect to another database. Here is a [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ed4d2720-fc6b-41e1-bdde-a21a56216a0b/solving-sql-server-connection-string-error-login-failed-for-user-for-aspnet-mvc-web-application?forum=ssdsgetstarted) like you, he could connect SSMS but still login failed.